# Javascript: do extended ASCII characters take up more memory?

Tags: javascript, utf-8, ascii, extended-ascii

I'm working on a routine to pack a dictionary, so I need to search for common letter combinations and replace them with only 1 character.

I already used up all 'normal' ASCII (<128) characters, but now I'm wondering if I can use the 128-255 range as well.

Or do these characters use more than 1 byte anyway ? I remember UTF-8 sometimes uses 2 or 3 bytes for special characters. All my javascript files use UTF-8 encoding.

So the question is, do ü, å, ê use the same amount of memory/disk space as u, a or e ?

Comment: Yes they use an additional 8 bits

Comment: Javascript is written on top of c in most browsers. This blog explains how c handles extended ascii http://core.ecu.edu/csci/wirthj/Basen/asciiCode-c.html

Comment: @megawac The title says "do they use more memory" and the last sentence is "do they use the same memory".  If someone answers "yes", this gets confusing.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript uses either UTF-16 or UCS-2 internally.  The amount of memory for a given character depends on how strings are handled in the particular JavaScript engine implementation.  It is probably safe to say though that at least 2 bytes will be used for each character.  For the characters you list, the same 2 bytes will be used for each character.

Reference:  http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding